# IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 is missing Run/Debug windows

Tags: java, intellij-idea

After updating my IntelliJ IDEA (from 13.0.3 to 13.1) the **Run/Debug windows** do not show. The corresponding menu entries in `View | Tool Windows` are deactivated.

I have tried editing .idea/workspace.xml or using the plugin "ToolWindow Manager" to show them manually, however then the windows are empty - no buttons or anything.

`Help | About` shows the correct Java JRE.

How can I bring them back?

**Update: problem solved, see comments:** examine log file and uninstall the plugin that is throwing an exception

Comment: Don't you even have the buttons below the menu bar?

Comment: Look into log for exceptions

Comment: Related? http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122436

Comment: Thanks Meo! After examining the log file and deactivating the incompatible plugin (VisualVM Launcher) the problem is solved.

Comment: There is already a new compatible version..,.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but specifically in Goland: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-8309

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you have a plugin that is disrupting the execution of the ide?

I had very similar issue today when upgrading from 13.0 to 13.1.  None of my gradle tasks were running and the Run/debug windows were not appearing.  When I started one of my run targets it froze and did not start until I exited the IDE.

After looking at the idea logs in [userdir]/.IdeaIC13/system/log I found the idea.log riddled with exceptions from the plugin GrepConsole.  I probably had an old version of this plugin.  To resolve the issue I just uninstalled the plugin using the IDEA plugin uninstall feature.  After restarting IDEA 13.1 the IDE is working just fine.

A support request was sent to Intellij on this with these findings:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/requests/24625

and also the author of the GrepConsole plugin was alerted here: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125?pr=phpStorm

Comment: Did IntelliJ not show you that there was already a new version of the plugin?

Comment: We do not have an access to the support request

Comment: Nothing was obvious in the ide ui that indicated there was a problem with the plugin or it was out of date.  I did not run Help | Check for Updates.  Perhaps that would have found it.  The author of the plugin suspected I had an old version of the plugin that presented its incompatibilities with the 13.1 version.  After reinstalling the new version of Grep Console the errors did not return.

Comment: I had this same problem caused by an old plugin, but I'm using a Mac and couldn't find a log in that location. However IntelliJ has a menu option **Help** | **Show Log in Finder** which took me to the actual location of the logs on my machine.

Comment: Thanks, the tip to look at the idea.log helped me with a different misbehaving plugin (PHP) that was causing similar troubles when upgrading to IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.1.

Answer (score 2):

For me the windows were simply under "Services". (Alt+8)